# Squid Cacheing HTTPS with peek and splice

Tags: proxy, ssl, cache

Ok. I'm confused. I want to create a cache proxy server to help minimize data and bandwidth usage (which is only 100GB a month). I've setup a virtual server that seems to help a bit, however I've read that squid won't save SSL/TLS because of CA. Does Peek and Splice make it possible and if not how can I setup a proxy cache without having to "Hack" the CA cert and give a fake one for clients to except the https sites? I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04 64x with squid 3.

Answer (score -1):

the way TLS works is that any party (to the conversation) who wishes to send data must use a private key to encrypt (the corresponding public key is part of the certificate).  Only the certificate owners have this key, and this is why intermediaries that inspect or cache https traffic must generate new certificates (as they cannot obtain the private key from the original server, so cannot use the original cert).  There's just no way round that.

Comment: loving the down-votes for telling the truth.  There's no way to do MitM without "hacking" your own certificates.  And yes, I do know, because I actually wrote a proxy server that does this.